# Okular extremely slow when printing?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, opensuse

I'm using Okular to view PDF files with KDE. I'm quite happy with it, the only problem is when printing a file: after selecting "Print" or "Print preview" from the file menu, Okular freezes for about 30 seconds. After that printing works quite well.

Evince for example doesn't have the same problem.

I'm using Okular on OpenSuse 11.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the openSUSE forums:

> [it appears that it was an IPv6 issue. I disabled IPv6 because of slow DNS lookups, and this issue is also now gone. thanks for the reply!](http://forums.opensuse.org/hardware/407798-clicking-print-okular-kde-causes-freeze.html)